# Filtering Django Objects and displaying data to HTML

Tags: python, html, django, database, orm

I have a Django web app which I want to do some basic filtering on. Basically, I have a social media like site where Users register their hobbies. What I want to do is have a filter where Users can choose to see only Male or Female users for now. Whilst I can do this in the Python Shell with the following code:

```
from mainapp.models import Profile
Users = Profile.objects.all().filter(gender = "Male")
```

I am having trouble with implementing this in Django. Here is my models.py file:

```
class Hobby(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        to=User,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, default='')
    age = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='')
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images')
    hobbies = models.ManyToManyField(Hobby)
```

The filter function which is in the Views.py file:

```
def filter(user):
    other_users = Profile.objects.all()
    filter_results = other_users.filter(gender = "Male")
    context = {
    'appname': appname,
    'usersresults': filter_results
    }
    return render(request, 'mainapp/members.html', context)
```

The Urls part:

```
path('filter/', views.filter, name='filter'),
```

And the HTML code:

```
<ul>
    {% for user in usersresults %}
        <li>
            <a> {{user}}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>
```

However, this does not work as expected and does not return anything to the display. I am not sure why this is going wrong - any help/advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For my function views I pass a request, and then any kwargs I need after that. I haven't tried the way you have it so just putting that out there in case it's part of the problem. In this case I don't think you need to pass user since it's not a variable in your urls and you aren't using it to filter the query. You also might consider renaming the variables to make it clearer for you in case you also decide to filter for female users:

```
def filter(request):
    template = 'mainapp/members.html'
    male_users = Profile.objects.filter(gender="Male")
    context = {
    'male_users': male_users
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

And then in the template:

```
<ul>
    {% for male in male_users %}
        <li>
            <a> {{ male.user }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```